# Got an error while building Wayland: ERROR: Program 'dot' not found

Tags: dot, meson-build, wayland

I am following instructions in wayland's gitlab [website](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland) to build it on Ubuntu 20.04. But I got an error at the "meson build" step:

```
Program dot found: NO

doc/meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Program 'dot' not found
```

I have tried installing `graphviz` using apt-get, `pydot` using pip3, but still receive the above error. What else should I install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the documentation built, just running `meson setup $builddir -Ddocumentation=false` will turn off the documentation, and thus the need for dot.

But it's confusing that graphviz isn't fixing the problem, since that is the Debian/Ubuntu package with dot in it.

Comment: I find the culpret: the dot in graphviz is actually a link to `../sbin/libgvc6-config-update`. This belongs to another package `libgvc6`. After installing this package, meson can find 'dot'. But after that, meson continues to complain not being able to find other things like doxygen, xsltproc, xmlto, ... I hope in the future, these building or installing tools can automatically download needed things from internet and install without complaining "Error: xxx not found", just as latex has already done decades before.

Answer (score 0):

right, if you use ubuntu just `sudo apt install graphviz` to get `doc/meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Program 'dot' not found`  resolved, or if you dont want to relly with `graphviz`. we can directly `sudo apt install libgvc6` as @zzzhhh said.

indeed afterthat for some reason mason might continue complaining not being able find anyothers: doxygen, xsltproc, xmlto, etc.

> I hope in the future, these building or installing tools can automatically download needed things from internet and install without complaining "Error: xxx not found"

yes, ther's it is, you can use `build-dep`.
eg: `sudo apt build-dep <SOURCE NAME YOU WANT TO BUILD>`.
ie. i want to build wayland from source: `sudo apt build-dep wayland`, then download tar.gz released or cloned by tag released and go with your `meson setup build`

Answer (score 0):

to resolve `dot` meson dependency, using `apt-get` you might need to install `python3-pydot`:

`sudo apt install python3-pydot`